# Argument Passing Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the function that i am executing:

```
def concat(*args, sep='/'):
    return sep.join(args)
```

When i try to pass this below arguments it executes right

```
>>> concat('earth', 'mars', 'venus')
```

Output:
'earth/mars/venus'

But when i pass below argument i get an extra dot at the end why?

```
>>> concat('earth', 'mars', 'venus', ".")
```

Output: 'earth/mars/venus/.'

And yes i know that after *args parameter we have to use ‘keyword-only’ arguments but my question is if this is the case why isn't it giving any error instead. why extra dot at the end?

Comment: Because it's treating "." as one of the `args` to be concatenated, not the separator.

Comment: if you want to change the separator, pass `'.'` as `sep='.'` instead: `concat('earth', 'mars', 'venus', sep='.')`

Comment: what else would you expect? why would it make any difference to use 3 or 4 parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sort of situation, you must explicitly name the argument you're passing.

```
concat('earth', 'mars', 'venus', sep=".")
```

This is the way Python 3's `print()` works, by the way.